# Output stylus loop variable in selector

Tags: stylus

I am trying to use a for loop to generate selectors and properties but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
colours = cola lychee lemonade tonic cherry ginger pineapple lemon lime elderflower cream-soda cream-soda-diet blackberry blueberry grape tropical raspberry 
cola = #1f2023
lychee = #9ca6b1
lemonade = #e0e5ed
tonic = #f8f9fa
cherry = #f7362b
ginger = #f79945
pineapple = #ffad00
lemon = #f5d600
lime = #6ecc54
elderflower = #4acccf
cream-soda = #00abff
cream-soda-diet = #F2FBFF
blackberry = #45388c
blueberry = #8f78e8
grape = #663da6
tropical = #cc78d1
raspberry = #fc007a
bubblegum = #f78cbf

button
    for colour in colours
        &.{colour}
            background colour
```

I want it to output something like this:

```
button.cola {
    background: #1f2023;
}
button.lychee {
    background: #9ca6b1
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Stylus [hashes](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/hashes.html) would be the way to go here.

```
colours = {
  cola: #1f2023
  lychee: #9ca6b1
  lemonade: #e0e5ed
  tonic: #f8f9fa
  cherry: #f7362b
  // etc
}

button
    for colour, value in colours
        &.{colour}
            background value
```

generates [the output you're looking for](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=colours%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20cola%3A%20%231f2023%0A%20%20lychee%3A%20%239ca6b1%0A%20%20lemonade%3A%20%23e0e5ed%0A%20%20tonic%3A%20%23f8f9fa%0A%20%20cherry%3A%20%23f7362b%0A%7D%0A%0Abutton%0A%20%20%20%20for%20colour%2C%20value%20in%20colours%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26.%7Bcolour%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background%20value).